# How can I fix corrupted encrypted wallet.dat?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, encryption

My only one backup of encrypted wallet is corrupted (last time when backed it up i probably didn't shutdown bitcoin-qt), with hex editor i found in it:

- mkey
- ckey (117 that looks fine)

Does this enough for recovering my private keys? at least 117 of them?

How can i do this?

**PS**
Already tried pywallet without success:
`ERROR:root:Couldn't open wallet.dat/main`
Bitcoin-qt: `wallet.dat corrupt, salvage failed`

Answer (score 4):

Found out that [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet) has recovery feature, and it worked:

Created 1GB FAT32 partition on flash drive(/dev/sdb1 in my case), copied corrupted wallet.dat on it and run:

`nyaa@ubuntu:~/github/pywallet$ sudo ./pywallet.py --recover --recov_device /dev/sdb1 --recov_size 1Gio --recov_outputdir /home/nyaa/
...
All the found encrypted private keys have been decrypted.
The wallet is encrypted and the passphrase is correct`

One of change addresses with all bitcoins on it was there!

Comment: Do you know if this can be run on an entire 120 Gigabyte drive using --recov_size 120Gio. Alternatively, could one also possibly cut and paste all relevant parts found by a hex editor from the drive into a new file and run pywallet, or would the file need to be at a certain level of "completeness" to start? Also, you mentioned formatting drive to fat32, is that necessary or can it be ext3 or ext4? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What would be the equivalent on windows if my drive is F:  ? I entered the command but I get "You must provide the device, the number of bytes to read and the output directory".